# What function releases a ID3D11Texture2D?

Tags: winapi, directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

I create a currTexture of type ID3D11Texture2D via a call to

```
ID3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&m_desc, NULL, &currTexture);
```

What is the proper way to release the resources assigned to this Texture2D? There does not exist a ReleaseTexture2D()-function or something like that…

Thanks! :-)

Comment: call `Release` on interface. `currTexture->Release()` in your case

Comment: [COM Managing the Lifetime of an Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-the-lifetime-of-an-object)

Comment: And if you aren't familiar with COM at this basic level I suggest you gain that familiarity before proceeding with DX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does exists a `Release` method as you can see in the docs:

["The ID3D11Texture2D interface inherits from ID3D11Resource"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11texture2d).

["The ID3D11Resource interface inherits from ID3D11DeviceChild"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11resource).

["The ID3D11DeviceChild interface inherits from the IUnknown interface"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11devicechild).

And [the IUnknown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iunknown) has method `Release`.

So call `currTexture->Release()` when you are done with it.